# How do I connect to the Remix JavaScript VM from my front end

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I have been developing using Remix and Metamask but it's a slow progress when pushing to the test networks. I have switched to the JS VM in Remix but I am not sure about how to connect my frontend to it. At the minute this is what I am using, I assume it is this bit of code that I need to change.

```
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    //web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, I just want to connect to the contracts in the JS VM. Thanks

Comment: It might be more convinient at this stage to start using [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/).

Answer (score -2):

Switch from vm to Injected Web3 and unlock you metamask, next time you click Create it will deploy contract using metamask to current network. You just copy address you are given and use it in front end.